# Capabilities & Linux & Java

Tags: java, linux, linux-capabilities

I am experimenting with Linux capabilities for java application. I do not want to add capabilities to interpreter (JVM), so I tried to write a simple wrapper (with debugging information printed to stdout):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/capability.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
        cap_t cap = cap_get_proc();

        if (!cap) {
                perror("cap_get_proc");
                exit(1);
        }
        printf("%s: running with caps %s\n", argv[0], cap_to_text(cap, NULL));

        return execlp("/usr/bin/java", "-server", "-jar", "project.jar", (char *)NULL);
}
```

This way, I can see that the capability is set for this executable:

```
./runner: running with caps = cap_net_bind_service+p
```

And `getcap` shows

```
runner = cap_net_bind_service+ip
```

I have the capability set to be inheritable, so there should be no problem. However, java still doesn't want to bind to privileged ports.

I am getting this error:

```
sun/nio/ch/Net.java:-2:in `bind': java.net.SocketException: Permission denied (NativeException)
```

Can someone help me to resolve this?

Comment: "java still don't want to bind to privileged ports": What error message do you get? It's possible that your JRE implementation does its own (wrong) check for `uid==0` before it attempts to bind to a privileged port.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a port above 1024, or run as root.

Comment: Ports below 1024 are privileged and can only be accessed by root.

Answer (score 0):

Any update?

You may find some answers in the Apache Commons-Daemon jsvc project: "...set of libraries and applications for making Java applications run on UNIX more easily."

- Project: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/jsvc.html
- Source: http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/commons/proper/daemon/trunk/src/native/unix/native/jsvc-unix.c?view=markup

They uses capabilities, even if they don't allow the user to select which one to apply, for portability reasons I suppose.